# What does bundle install --without production do?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, rubygems, bundler

Ive seen people using this and used it myself as told to do so. I just dont have a real grasp as what it actually does. I understand fully the `bundle install` part, but not the `--without production` part of it. What does this do and why would I want to use it?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

If you have a group inside your Gemfile like

```
group :production do
    gem 'whatever'
end
```

Then when you run your bundle command on your development machine, it won't install the gems intended for use in your production environment. Basically only installing the gems you need in development on your development machine.

Comment: So by default does bundler install all gems, regardless of group, but only load specific gems on app startup when it can detect the runtime environment?

Answer (score 8):

As you seen some people using following command(Which you said in your question):

```
bundle install --without production
```

`--without production` is a special flag which we are using.

For more explanation I am taking following example:

```
group :production do
  gem 'pg', '0.12.2'
end
```

Now, If I use following command:

```
bundle install --without production
```

In above command, the `--without production` option prevents the local installation of any production gem means whatever gems are in the production group will not be installed -- which in our example is just one gem: `pg`.

Answer (score 1):

As it's mentioned on [bundler docs](https://bundler.io/man/bundle-install.1.html#OPTIONS),

> This option is deprecated in favor of the `without` setting.

So, to avoid installing production group gems now one would use:

```
$ bundle config without production
```

[To read more](https://bundler.io/v1.16/bundle_config.html#DESCRIPTION)