# Could not find pg-0.17.1-x86-mingw32 in any of the sources

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I'm new to rails, and am working through a tutorial in which I've just finished pushing to app to Heroku. I was instructed to add these gems to the gemfile:

```
group :production do
    gem 'pg'
    gem 'rails_12factor'
end

group :development, :test do
     gem 'sqlite3'
end
```

After that I run bundle install through Gitbash, however when I go to restart the local server I get the error: **Could not find pg-0.17.1-x86-mingw32 in any of the sources**

I'm running a Windows 7 32 bit machine, any ideas how I can resolve this issue?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You don't really need the pg gem installed on your development machine since you're using SQLite as your development and test db.

If you use `bundle install --without production` you'll avoid this problem.

[See this post for more info about using the `--without production` option](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19895395/what-does-bundle-install-without-production-do)

Comment: Worked perfectly, thanks! (To anyone reading, I used "bundle install --without production" the dash between without and production didn't work.)

Comment: I'm guessing when I want to push it back to heroku, I can just bundle install as normal, push to git, then push to heroku without running a local server?

Comment: Thanks for pointing out that typo, I've fixed it. Since you have the pg gem in your `:production` group, you shouldn't have to do anything differently when you push to Heroku. Heroku, being your production environment, should take care of installing the pg gem for you.